# How do I have a certain php script executed when the "deadline" according to the SQL is met?

Tags: php, sql

The easiest I could explain this is by giving this simple example:

Imagine an eBay auction, which ends at let's say 5:00 pm, this is set as an SQL value for the auction entry. (I have all date/times in unixtime).
Now, when the auction ends (the time hits 5:00 pm), the system sends an e-mail to the winner, plus executes other many actions (specified inside a php file?).

How would I do this? I can write the php, etc, but I don't know how to make the 'site' execute it every time some auction ends?

I think I need to use CRON, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: You can use a database trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use CRON jobs then they will be fired after every fixed interval.. So here is the solution..

Make a CRON job and schedule it every 1 or 2 minute or even 5 minute. and in that PHP script check any auction which has expired and then send email to the winner..

e.g.

```
$sql = "select * from auctions where auctionEndTime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";

//execute query
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   //send email and other tasks
}
```

Comment: I tend to not insert cron jobs with a higher frequency then */5 (every 5 minutes) and never */1. Cron does not run exactly on the minute. Also, you really want a where clause that looks like this: `WHERE closed=0 AND auctionEndTime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` as the above query returns a staggering amount of rows over time.

Comment: @Mel, Thanks for your suggestion, +1 for you.. However I was giving just an idea..